WordPress Custom Header via plugin
I need to create custom header for my WordPress theme. But I need to do it via plugin. Something like I have prebuild header in my plugin. I need to set it to header and I need to remove theme default header.
I research everywhere but I couldn't find any resource for this.

So you come here to point out something you need to do in the hope that someone will do it for you?

Please use the below code to load the header from plugin.
add_action('get_header', function(){
    require PLUGIN_DIR.'includes/templates/header.php';
    $templates   = [];
    $templates[] = 'header.php';
    remove_all_actions( 'wp_head' );
    ob_start();
    locate_template( $templates, true );
    ob_get_clean();
});


It worked. But it removed all of the head links such as scripts and styling sheets

I fixed it. Thanks for the response and answer.
